# Contrasts are giving wrong estimates using glht in R

Tags: r, contrasts, lme4-nlme

**The problem:** glht is giving the direct differences between the estimates of the summary table (i.e., not summing each estimate with the intercept to obtain the estimated value).

```
contrast1 <- matrix(c(1 , -1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ,
              0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0), 1)

library(multcomp)
> glht(fitted.model, linfct = contrast1)

     General Linear Hypotheses

Linear Hypotheses:
       Estimate
1 == 0     -1.2
```

The correct contrast should calculate the predicted value for each treatment, then use the predicted values to obtain the estimated diffences.

Linear Hypotheses:
       Estimate
1 == 0     -1.2   **# This is should be -0.007748148 instead of -1.2**

```
> summary(fitted.model)$tTable[1,1]-   (summary(fitted.model)$tTable[1,1]+summary(fitted.model)$tTable[2,1])
[1] -0.007748148
```

I am analyzing a study with two factors (FactorA: 4 Insecticides; FactorB: 9 Evaluation dates) conducted in 2014 and 2015 (2 years). The response variable (Y) was recorded in different leaves of the plants, 3 plants per plot, 5 replications per treatment in a randomized complete block design.

A subset of the dataset:

```
library(gsheet)
mydata <- gsheet2tbl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zPcN0eiCPC829zssAiaPtYMxmDdk3F7pmvrBZc0vhTE/edit?usp=sharing")
mydata[,2:9] <- lapply(mydata[,2:9], as.factor)

> summary(mydata[,1:6])
       Y             Year      Block        Plot      Plant   Leaf    
 Min.   :0.03947   2014:1685   1:597   2      :  97   1:926   1 :567  
 1st Qu.:0.05921   2015:1119   2:537   4      :  91   2:941   2 :597  
 Median :0.06342               3:525   17     :  91   3:937   3 :588  
 Mean   :0.06512               4:575   12     :  90           4 :501  
 3rd Qu.:0.06930               5:570   13     :  90           5 :228  
 Max.   :0.19497                       3      :  89           6 : 23  
                                       (Other):2256           UN:300
```

Here is the model I am using:

```
fitted.model<-lme(log10(Y)~FactorA*FactorB, random=~ 1|Year/Block/Plot/Plant/Leaf,  
                       data=mydata, method="ML", control=lmeControl(opt='optim'))
```